# Webhook input not available in scripting step?

Tags: zapier

I have an internal app that uses a webhook listener and some scripting to manipulate the input data.  I'm posting this to it:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
    "assignment_id": 12345,
    "updated_custom_fields": [{
        "name": "RNVIDAYEBB",
        "value": "updated!"
      },
      {
        "name": "QUFTXSIBYA",
        "value": "and me too"
      }
    ],
    "custom_fields": [{
        "id": 981,
        "name": "RDEXDPVKRD",
        "fields": [
          {
            "id": 4096,
            "name": "RNVIDAYEBB",
            "default": "EDJEAJICYW",
            "required": true,
            "value": "Blah"
          },
          {
            "id": 4097,
            "name": "QUFTXSIBYA",
            "default": "",
            "required": true,
            "value": ""
          }]
     }]
}' "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/......"
```

My script is as follows:

```
update_custom_fields_by_name_pre_write: function(bundle) {
    var updatedFields = _.map(bundle.request.data.custom_fields, function(group) {
        return _.map(group.fields, function(field) {
            return _.extend(field, _.findWhere(bundle.request.data.updated_custom_fields, { name: field.name} ));
        });
    });
    bundle.request.data = updatedFields;
    return bundle.request;  
}
```

I know that the merging logic is good, but it appears that the `custom_fields` and `updated_custom_fields` arrays are not present in the bundle.request.data object.  Anyone know how to get access to them in the script?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be using `update_custom_fields_by_name_catch_hook` to capture the incoming static webhook data (instead of `_pre_write`). If you use that, you can capture the data within `bundle.cleaned_request.custom_fields` and `bundle.cleaned_request.updated_custom_fields`.